# Interval of Definition of First Order DE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking at a walkthrough solution for the differential equation:
$x\frac{dy}{dx} - 4y = x^6e^x$

Putting this equation in standard form we get:

$\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{4}{x}y = x^5e^x$

This is a first order DE that may be solved using an integrating factor.

I understand that the interval of definitions (otherwise known as interval of existance/interval of validity/domain of the solution) for the general solution are: (-$\infty$,0) and (0, $\infty$). My reasoning is that both  $\frac{4}{x}$ and $x^5e^x$ are continuous and differentiable on those intervals whilst 0 is a singular point.

According to my textbook however, they mention that "f and P are continuous on (0,$\infty$)". The text then proceeds to provide a general solution over the interval (0, $\infty$). Whilst I dont see that statement as wrong, they do seem to ignore the interval (-$\infty$,0). Is there any reason for this?

Comment: What's f and P?

Comment: Ive edited the question to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your choice of looking at this on $(0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty, 0)$.  They happened to choose $(0,\infty)$.  There is no particular justification, except that if you think of $x$ as representing "time", some people are more interested in the future than the past.

Comment: Would it be mathematically correct to state that there are intervals (emphasis on the plural) of definition rather than a choice between two intervals of definition?

Comment: Yes, it would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{4}{x} y=x^5 e^x.$$ The integrating factor is $$I=e^{-\int 4/x dx}= x^{-4}.$$ then the solution is
$$y=(I)^{-1} \int I x^5 e^x dx+ CI^{-1} \implies y= x^4 e^x (x-1) +C x^4.$$
Here $C$ is constant of integration.